# yii : $model->save() inserts null values when we I have empty rules

Tags: php, yii

I don't have any rules for the input fields, (name,place, position) so my model's rules function returns an empty array, but then empty values are getting saved into the database table.

```
public function rules()
{
    return array();
}
```

Also when I omit rules() function from my model

> $model->save()

returns true but DB table get inserted with empty values.

so how can I omit rules() function from my model class ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you should set all of them as `safe` attribute in rules.

```
public function rules(){
    return array
       array('id, name, /*list attribute here*/', 'safe')
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define `safe` attribute in rules.

```
public function rules(){
    return array(
       array('id, name, place, postion', 'safe')
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Key Point - Massive Assignment will only be made for fields which have passed some explicit validation rule.